# How to determine the length of an array?

Tags: arrays, sas

If I dont know the exact length of an array after a transpose, is there a way to output it? or to use it, without manually looking through the output data?
For example, if I transpose on number of pills dispensed, but that number is variable for each 'id' and then I want to specify that array in a regression, is there a way to do it without finding the value via manual visual inspection?

```
PROC PHREG DATA=...;
ARRAY start{*} start1-start????;
DO I=1 TO ?????;
IF  start{I}<t2event THEN var=1;
END;
MODEL .........
```

As a corollary if I know that its less than say, 100, and I specify 100, would there be any consequence?
Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

The DIM() function returns the dimensions of an array.  You can use the : suffix to make a variable list of names that start with the same letters.

```
 ARRAY start{*} start: ;
 DO I=1 TO dim(start);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a do over loop:

```
ARRAY start{*} col1 col5 col8 var1;
DO OVER start;
```

Comment: I believe DO OVER loops have been deprecated :( They still work but are not supported.

Comment: You cannot use the `{*}` in the array definition if you want to use the array with `do over`.